# jQuery make automatic slider via intervals, timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, slider, setinterval

Hello guys I'm a beginner at coding and I would like to ask you if you know how to make this 
slider, slide automatically every 5 seconds.

Here is the code of the slider;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
"use strict";


//prev = top
//current = middle
//next = bottom

var windowHeight = $(window).height();

$('.slide:first-child').addClass('current');
$('.slide:nth-child(2)').addClass('next').css('top', windowHeight);

$(window).resize(function() {
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('.slide.next').css('top', windowHeight);
    $('.slide.prev').css('top', -windowHeight);
});

if (!$('.slide.current').next('.slide').length) { $('#next').hide(); }
if (!$('.slide.current').prev('.slide').length) { $('#prev').hide(); }

function nextSlide() {
    var current = $('.slide.current'),
            next = current.next('.slide'),
            prev = current.prev('.slide');

    if (next.length) {
        current.animate({
            top: -windowHeight
        }, 300);
        next.animate({
            top: 0
        }, 300);
        prev.removeClass('prev');
        current.removeClass('current').addClass('prev');
        next.removeClass('next').addClass('current');
        next.next('.slide').addClass('next').css('top', windowHeight);

        if (!$('.slide.current').next('.slide').length) {
            $('#next').hide();
            $('#prev').show();
        } else {
            $('#next').show();
        }
    }
}


function prevSlide() {
    var current = $('.slide.current'),
            next = current.next('.slide'),
            prev = current.prev('.slide');

    if (prev.length) {
        current.animate({
            top: windowHeight
        }, 300);
        prev.animate({
            top: 0
        }, 300);
        next.removeClass('next');
        current.removeClass('current').addClass('next');
        prev.removeClass('prev').addClass('current');
        prev.prev('.slide').addClass('prev').css('top', -windowHeight);

        if (!$('.slide.current').prev('.slide').length) {
            $('#prev').hide();
            $('#next').show();
        } else {
            $('#prev').show();
        }
    }
}



$('#next').live('click', function() {
    nextSlide();
    return false;
});

$('#prev').live('click', function() {
    prevSlide();
    return false;
});
```

I tried something with setInterval but didn't quite work as I would like it to,

```
setInterval(function(){
$('#next, #prev').trigger('click');
```

}, 4000
);

This slides one slide down after 5 seconds, then it continuously slides up and down every 1 second.

I want the slides to slide like this in a loop: 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1

THANK YOU!

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, figured it out

```
var flag = false; 
setInterval ( function() { 
    if (flag == false){
        nextSlide();
        if($('.slide.next').length == 0) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        prevSlide();
        if($('.slide.prev').length == 0) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
}, 6000);
```

Thank you

CLOSE;